# Multiple plots using loops in R

Tags: r, loops, plot, dataframe

I'm still trying to get my head around using loops to plot in R. I would like to plot (any plot to visualise the data will do) columns z_1 against z_2 in the data frame below according to the different names in column x_1.

```
x_1 <- c("A1", "A1","A1", "B10", "B10", "B10","B10", "C100", "C100", "C100")


z_1 <- rnorm(10, 70) 

z_2 <- rnorm(10, 1.7)

A <- data.frame(x_1, z_1, z_2)
```

As such, I would like to end up with three different plots; one for category A1, one for B10 and another for C100. I can do this using three different codes but I would like to be able to use a loop or any other single code to execute all three plots on the same page. In reality, I have a large dataset (4,000 rows) and would like to plot a couple of IDs on a page (say 5 on a page).

I hope this makes sense. Thanks for your help.

Here's my attempt at plotting them individually:

for A1:

```
data_A1 <- A[which(A$x_1 == "A1"), ]
plot(data_A1$z_2, data_A1$z_1)
```

I also tried something like this but getting error messages

```
for ( i in A$x_1[[i]]){

plot(A[which(A$x_1==A$x_1[[i]]), ], aspect = 1)
}
```

Comment: If you showed an actual attempt that you've made thus far, and explain how it didn't work, I might be tempted to help.

Comment: @joran, I'll edit my post to include my attempt so far. Thanks.

Comment: Small thing, but you're making the common mistake of over-using `which`. Try running `x <- runif(10)`, then compare `x[x < 0.5]` and `x[which(x < 0.5)]`. As in your code above, you can omit `which` to get the same result.

Comment: @ Shujaa, any chance you could help re-write my original code to make it work?

Comment: @John I'll add an answer dissecting where your code doesn't work, but we'll basically arrive at Mark's answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A simple approach with loops would be

```
for (cat in unique(x_1)){
  d <- subset(A, x_1 == cat)
  plot(d$z_1, d$z_2)
}
```

`unique(x_1)` gets you all the unique values of `x_1`. Then, for each of these values get a corresponding subset and use this subset for plotting.

Comment: @ Mark Heckmann, Thank you so much for the codes, it works beautifully. I'm trying to edit it to make it plot all three on a single page using the layout function-not quite there yet.

Comment: @ Mark Heckmann, I've just had a second look at the code. I'm not too sure why i'm getting just the C100 category as an output for d in the above code. Why does it give the C100 category as opposed to A1 or B10?

Comment: @John I cannot reproduce you problem, please elaborate. For me it works fine.

Comment: I'm really sry to bother you. I've just executed the code again to be sure. My output for `d <- subset(A, x_1==cat)` gives me the ff 3 rows:  8 C100 71.08877 1.892950, 9 C100 71.29257 1.144764, 10 C100 71.28251 1.974991. Is this not what you're getting?

Comment: @John The point of the for loop is that `d` gets overwritten each time, once for each unique value of `x_1`. Since `C100` is the last value, when the for loop is finished `d` will be in it's final state.

Comment: @shujaa, thank you so much for the clarification, it makes so much sense now.

Answer (score 23):

Just to understand why your original code didn't work:

Setting up data works fine

```
x_1 <- c("A1", "A1", "A1", "B10", "B10", "B10","B10", "C100", "C100", "C100")
z_1 <- rnorm(10, 70) 
z_2 <- rnorm(10, 1.7)
A <- data.frame(x_1, z_1, z_2)
```

The individual plot works fine, but as I said in a comment, the `which` is unnecessary

```
data_A1 <- A[which(A$x_1 == "A1"), ] # your way
plot(data_A1$z_2, data_A1$z_1)

data_A1 <- A[A$x_1 == "A1", ]    # deleting which() makes it cleaner
with(data_A1, plot(z_2, z_1))    # you can also use with() to save typing
```

Now the for loop. Let's review a simple for loop in R (pretty close to the example in `?"for"`):

```
for (i in 1:5) {
   print(1:i)
}
```

Pretty straightforward, `1:5` is `c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`, so first `i` is `1`, then `2`, etc. Your for loop has a problem in that first line:

```
for (i in A$x_1[[i]]) { ## already a problem
```

First `i` is `A$x_1[[i]]`? That won't work, `i` isn't defined yet. Also, `A$x_1` is a vector, not a list, so you shouldn't be using `[[` to subset it. But we don't want a subset yet, we want a vector of the values `i` should take. What we want in this case is `for (i in c("A1", "B10", "C100"))`, but we also want to do it programmatically instead of typing out all the different possibilities. There's a couple common ways to get that:

```
unique(A$x_1) # as in Mark's solution
levels(A$x_1) # works because A$x_1 is a factor
```

We can put either of those expressions after the `in`. I changed your `[[` to `[` in the plot call. `[[` is for lists only. I also took out the unnecessary `which()`

```
for (i in unique(A$x_1)) {   # this line is good
    plot(A[A$x_1==A$x_1[i], ], aspect = 1)  # still a problem
}
```

Let's remind ourselves what values `i` is taking: `"A1"`, `"B10"`, `"C100"`. What's `A$x_1 == A$x_1["A1"]` going to give? Nothing useful.

```
for (i in unique(A$x_1)) {  
    plot(A[A$x_1 == i, ], aspect = 1)  # getting there
}
```

The above code plots something, and it's neat, but it's not what you want. There's a bunch of warnings, all of them telling us that `aspect` isn't a valid argument, so we'll delete it. Looking at the plot, you'll see that it's plotting 3 variables, because we haven't told it what to put on the x and y axes.

```
for (i in unique(A$x_1)) {   
    plot(A[A$x_1==i, "z_2"], A[A$x_1==i, "z_1"])  # z_2 on x, z_1 on y 
}   # Works!!!
```

Notice that this is almost identical to Mark's answer. You don't have to use `i` and `j` in for loops, he used `cat`. It's good practice to use a more descriptive name.
Now let's fancy it up a little:

```
for (i in unique(A$x_1)) {   
    plot(A[A$x_1==i, "z_2"], A[A$x_1==i, "z_1"],
         xlim = range(A$z_2), ylim = range(A$z_1), # base the axes on full data range
         main = paste("Plot of", i))  # Give each a title
}
```

**Next time:** don't forget that you can run tiny pieces of code to see what they are. If you have a line like `for (i in A$x_1[[i]])` that you're not sure if it's right, enter `A$x_1[[i]]` at the console, hopefully that will help you figure out that you haven't defined `i`, so you'll change it to

```
for (i in A$x_1)
```

then you run `A$x_1` and realize it's length is 10. You want 3 graphs, not 10, so you need `i` to take 3 values, all of them different, etc.

Comment: that was brilliant! This is probably the best answer I've ever received from this forum. Now I understand loops a lot better. thanks shujaa.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you don´t need a loop. Try using ggplots facet_grid().
Here is the [documentation](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/), full of examples.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

melted_a <- melt(A)


ggplot(melted_a, aes(variable, value)) +
  geom_jitter() +
  facet_grid(. ~ x_1)

ggplot(melted_a, aes(variable, value)) +
  geom_jitter() +
  facet_grid(variable ~ x_1)
```

**Edit**
Perhaps this solves this problem. But if you need to do many plots that have a similar structure, you could make a function and use `aes_string()` instead of `aes()`. 
Note: I'm not an expert at writing functions, so probably someone could edit and improve it. (not tested)

```
ggplot_fun <- function(data, x, y, rowfacet, colfacet, ...){
  p <- ggplot(data, aes_string(x, y))
  p <- p + geom_jitter()
  p <- p + facet_grid(as.formula(sprintf("%s ~ %s", rowfacet, colfacet))
}

ggplot_fun(melted_a, variable, value, variable, x_1)
```

Idea taken from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19016007/metaprogramming-with-ggplot2).

Comment: @ Martin Bel, thank you so much for the useful references and codes, I shall take my time to read through them all.

Answer (score 1):

You also tweak around the data, for example like I did here....

If I want datewise plots and xlab, ylab and title of the plot to have specific details...

```
 for ( i in 1:length(unique(wheeldata$Date)) ){
     d <- subset( wheeldata, Date == unique ( wheeldata$Date )[i] )
     plot(d$X, d$Y, xlab = "X", ylab = "Y", main = paste0("Date: ",  unique(d$Date)) )
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ggplot_fun <- function(data, x, y, rowfacet, colfacet, ...){
p <- ggplot(data, aes_string(x, y))
p <- p + geom_jitter()
p <- p + facet_grid(as.formula(sprintf("%s ~ %s", rowfacet, colfacet))
}

ggplot_fun(melted_a, variable, value, variable, x_1)
```

I have tried the code above within a loop, but it didn't work. I just figured out that the `print` function is required to make it work. In case someone uses it and thinks it doesn't work.

Comment: Would you mind editing the code so that it includes the print function as you mentioned? If someone inexperienced with R comes about this answer, they may not know what to do exactly.