# Loop Through Dataframe to Create Plots in R

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2

I know there is a very similar question to this found here: [Multiple plots using loops in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20892266/multiple-plots-using-loops-in-r) but I have been trying to emulate it without success, though I think I am quite close. For simplicity, my dataframe, `district.charter.comp`, is as follows:

```
 city.state     count     school.type     Status
Stockton, CA     1417      charter     Beat the Odds
Stockton, CA     7242      charter    Not Beat the Odds
Stockton, CA     269       district    Beat the Odds
Stockton, CA    49737      district   Not Beat the Odds
 Newark, NJ     12528      charter     Beat the Odds
 Newark, NJ      3687      charter    Not Beat the Odds
 Newark, NJ      7129      district    Beat the Odds
 Newark, NJ     27257      district   Not Beat the Odds
```

For each city state, I want to create a unique mosaic or mekko plot. My current code is as follows:

```
district.charter.comp$city.state <- as.factor(district.charter.comp$city.state)

for(i in levels(district.charter.comp$city.state)) {
  mekko.plot <- district.charter.comp %>% filter(city.state == i) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_mosaic(aes(weight = count, x = product(school.type), fill = Status)) +
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none") +
  ggtitle(i) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
  mekko.plot
}
plot.data
```

However, when I view the plot, I get only `Stockton, CA` and the loop doesn't appear to be iterating through to the next factor level, namely `Newark, NJ`.
[image]

The loop should output two plots. One for `Stockton, CA` and another for `Newark, NJ`.

Comment: You are overwriting your earlier plots and so end up with just the last one. Either print them inside the loop or build a list of plot objects for storage.

Comment: Try wrapping your line of code that outputs the plot in `print()` (use `print(mekko.plot)` instead of just `mekko.plot`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider `by` (object-oriented wrapper to `tapply`) which is equivalent to looping through all levels of a factor. Plus, like the apply family functions, `by` returns an object or collection of objects (here being list) without the bookkeeping of initializing and assigning to an empty list.

```
mekko.plots <- by(district.charter.comp, district.charter.comp$city.state, function(sub) {
  ggplot(sub) +
    geom_mosaic(aes(weight = count, x = product(school.type), fill = Status)) +
    theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(),
          axis.title = element_blank(),
          axis.text = element_blank(),
          legend.position = "none") +
    ggtitle(sub$city.state[[1]]) +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
})

mekko.plots
```