# Accessing a variable in a ggplot function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a sample data below

```r
data <- data.frame(yr = c(1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005,
                          2006, 2007, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012), 
                   ntemp =c (11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 12, 23))
```

When I try running this function, to access the variable inside a ggplot function.

```r
FUN <- function(data, fun.y, yr) {
      fun.data <- data     
      ggplot(fun.data, aes(yr, fun.y)) +
      geom_point() +
      scale_y_continuous(fun.y)    
    }
    
FUN(data, "ntemp", yr)
```

I get an `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'fun.y' not found`

How can I solve this?

Comment: You are trying to map `fun.y`, which is supposed to be a variable in `fun.data`. Since it is not, you get an error.

Comment: I have passed fun.y in the function as ntemp

Comment: ```aes_string()``` is the way. If you would be interested in adding facets, here is a [question that migth help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19016007/metaprogramming-with-ggplot2).

Comment: If the proposed solution works for you, please do not forget to mark question as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`aes` only looks at the variables in `data` argument. If you would like to pass variable as an argument to `FUN` by its character name, use `aes_string`:

```
FUN <- function(data, x, y) {
  ggplot(data, aes_string(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point()
}

FUN(data, y="ntemp", x="yr")
```

A small correction: variable inside `aes` call should be defined in the scope where the ggplot object is evaluated, so technically a variable is looked up in data first, then in global environment (by default). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659133/local-variables-within-aes) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106782/use-of-ggplot-within-another-function-in-r) questions.

Comment: This gives me an error of Error in as.environment(where) : 'where' is missing